# knitr is not recognizing a function from lmtest package

Tags: r, knitr, lm

I've written the following function to isolate the durbin-watson statistic to include it in a table later in my LaTeX document:

```
DW                <- function(model) {
                          dw.mat <- matrix(dwtest(model))
                              dw     <- as.numeric(dw.mat[1,1])
}
```

I'm using the `dwtest` function from the `lmtest` package and the function seems to work fine in the console. However, when I use this function as part of a LaTeX document produced using knitr I get the following error:

```
## Error in matrix(dwtest(model)): could not find function "dwtest"
```

My .Rnw file begins with `require(lmtest)`

Why is `dwtest` not working when I compile the document?

I also get the same result using the `durbinWatsonTest` function in the `car` package.

Comment: I would use `library(lmtest)` instead of `require(lmtest)`. `library()` will throw an error if the package isn't found.

Comment: Also try install.packages()

Comment: Switching from `require` to `library` I get the additional error `## Error in library(lmtest): there is no package called 'lmtest'` I know I have the package installed since it works fine in the console. Can knitr not locate it?

Comment: have you checked .libPaths() from both the console and the execution of knitr? That's generally it. You're probably installing in a differentplace in the console

Comment: How do you call `knitr`? The "Knit to PDF" button in RStudio, from a command line, ...? Maybe `knitr` uses a different R version.

Answer (score 0):

jimmyb called it. I had been messing around with the `packrat` package the last time I had the package open and had unintentionally changed my default directory. When I then installed `lmtest` it was saved in the new directory, not the one `knitr` was looking in to find the package.

Thanks for the help!